# Circuit design that outputs square of binary input

Tags: boolean-logic, circuit, digital-logic, truthtable

So for my digital logic course, we were asked to design a combinational circuit with 3 inputs, and an output that generates the square of the binary input. I assume she means the inputs are 3 bit binary numbers 0-7. In describing the solution, she mentioned 3 general steps of 1. Finding truth table, 2. deriving the function  and 3. Simplifying

I understand perfectly how to do this when the output is a single function (combine the instances of a true function, simplify etc.) In our only relevant example, we input BCD numbers 0-9 and output their excess-3 equivalent, then simplified a k-map for each of the 4 output variables (a map for W, the leftmost bit, X the second-to-left bit, etc.). Not sure what to do from here tho. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you find the output for each input, you could create 6 K-maps (one for each output) of 3 variables, and use those to reduce the equation which can then be turned into a digital circuit.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, you need to fetch the inputs in binary, calculate the square in binary format (the binary length will increase from 3 to 6).

But, you don't need those BCD numbers and output their excess-3 equivalent. That would rather make the problem more complex. Simply do as directed below.

So, for the 3 different bit combinations, you need to generate a function in terms of combinational circuit that will yield a 6-bit square of the given number.

So, your input set = {b0,b1,b2} and your output set = {B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6}.

Then, you need to draw the truth table of 3-bit to 6-bit square converter as :-

```
Input       B6        B5         B4          B3          B2       B1        B0
```

---

```
  b0
  b1
  b2
```

Fill the entries, that's the homework for you.

And, then when you have output bits `B6,B5,...,B0` in terms of **`b0,b1 and b2`**, just simplify all the functions.

If you still have any doubt, comment below. I will help you with your issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I assumed I needed to do but I wanted to verify before doing all the work. The BCD-Ex3 was just a previous example where we did a similar circuit, it has no direct pertinence to this problem. When I create the 6 kmaps for b5-b0, do I combine the respective functions somehow or am I left with these 6 functions as my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Logic Friday 1` to derive the following minimized expression for the six outputs of your multiplier:

```
ab5 = a2 a1 b2 b1  + a2 a1 a0 b2 b0 + a2 a0 b2 b1 b0;
ab4 = a2 a1' a0' b2  + a2 a1' b2 b1'  + a2 a0' b2 b1'  
    + a2 a1' b2 b0' + a2 b2 b1' b0' + a2' a1 a0 b2 b1  
    + a2 a1 b2' b1 b0 + a1 a0 b2 b1 b0;
ab3 = a2' a1 a0' b2  + a2 a1' b2' b1  + a2' a1 b2 b1'  
    + a2 b2' b1 b0' + a2' a1 a0 b2' b1 b0 + a2 a1' a0 b2 b1' b0 
    + a1 a0' b2 b1' + a2 a1' b1 b0' + a2 a0' b2 b1 b0 
    + a2 a1 a0 b2 b0';
ab2 = a2' a1 a0' b1  + a2 a1' a0' b0 + a2 a0' b1' b0 
    + a1' a0 b2 b0' + a1 a0' b1 b0' + a1 b2' b1 b0' 
    + a0 b2 b1' b0' + a2' a0 b2 b0 + a2 a0 b2' b0;
ab1 = a1' a0 b1  + a1 a0' b0 + a1 b1' b0 + a0 b1 b0';
ab0 = a0 b0;
```

As a truth table:

[image]

The original truth table has 64 rows.

The largest output number is 49 = 7 * 7 = 32 + 16 + 1.
Therefore, six (= 3 + 3) output bits are sufficient.